# Binary math programming

Tags: c++, math, visual-studio-2013, binary

I have been asked to create a program that takes 2 binary numbers then outputs the result of adding, subtracting and multiplying them.  My code works for addition but when I try to do subtraction or multiplication, the output is not as expected.  The cout statement is displayed with each digit and several of the digits are incorrect.  Could anyone point to flaws in my code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    long num1, num2;
    int choice;
    int i = 0, r = 0, sum[20];

    cout << "Enter the first binary number: ";   //prompts user to input binary values to perform arithmetic on
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Enter the second binary number: ";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "To add the numbers press 1, to subtract the numbers press 2," << endl;  //prompts user to choose which operation to perform
    cout << "to multiply the numbers press 3" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice != 1 & choice != 2 & choice != 3)  //if statement to test for valid input
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }

    if (choice == 1) 
    {

        while (num1 != 0 || num2 != 0)     //if user chooses 1, perform binary arithmetic
        {
            sum[i++] = (num1 % 10 + num2 % 10 + r) % 2;
            r = (num1 % 10 + num2 % 10 + r) / 2;
            num1 = num1 / 10;
            num2 = num2 / 10;
        }
        if (r != 0)
            sum[i++] = r;
        --i;
        cout << "The sum of the two numbers is: ";


        while (i >= 0)
            cout << sum[i--];
        cout << ". ";
    }

    if (choice == 2)
    {

        while (num1 != 0 || num2 != 0)     //if user chooses 2, perform binary subtraction
        {
            int i = 0, r = 0, diff[20];
            diff[i++] = (num1 % 10 - num2 % 10 + r) % 2;
            r = (num1 % 10 - num2 % 10 + r) / 2;
            num1 = num1 / 10;
            num2 = num2 / 10;
            if (r != 0)
                diff[i++] = r;
            --i;
            cout << "The difference of the two numbers is: ";
            while (i >= 0)
                cout << diff[i--];
            cout << ". ";
        }
    }
    if (choice == 3)   //if user chooses 3, perform binary multiplication
    {

        while (num1 != 0 || num2 != 0)
        {
            int i = 0, r = 0, product[20];
            product[i++] = (num1 % 10 * num2 % 10 + r) % 2;
            r = (num1 % 10 * num2 % 10 + r) / 2;
            num1 = num1 / 10;
            num2 = num2 / 10;
            if (r != 0)
                product[i++] = r;
            --i;
            cout << "The product of the two numbers is: ";
            while (i >= 0)
                cout << product[i--];
            cout << ". ";
        }
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: This isn't to answer your question, but as general advice: start small. Make a program that adds two numbers together. Not in a loop, a simple 5 line program that adds 2 numbers. Now have it also subtract and multiple those numbers. Test multiple numbers. Then get the numbers from user input. Then put it in a loop. By doing small steps your code will become more manageable and you'll be able to see the exact thing that didn't work.

Comment: You have `if (choice != 1 & choice != 2 & choice != 3)`. I suspect you meant to use `if (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3)`

Comment: `if (choice != 1 & choice != 2 & choice != 3)` you may like rewrite as `if(choice > 3 || choice <1)` . Looks cleaner and lesser cpu.

Comment: *"but when I try to do subtraction or multiplication, the output is not as expected"* - be specific - what's the simplest (shortest) inputs for which those operations failed, what result did you actually see, and what don't you understand about where the processing went wrong (despite adding some `cout` trace and/or watching it in a debugger)?

Comment: @Ryan A :  I have written some code below ...have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to try something

```
int binary2decimal(int n) /* Function to convert binary to decimal.*/
{
    int decimal=0, i=0, rem;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        rem = n%10;
        n/=10;
        decimal += rem*pow(2,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal;
}

int main()
{
    ....
    ....
    if(!num1 || !num2)
    {
        cout << "Result = 0";
        exit(0);
    }

    .....

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:                   
             int r = binary2decimal(num1) + binary2decimal(num2);
             cout << "Result = " << r;
             break;

         case 2: 
             int r = binary2decimal(num1) - binary2decimal(num2);
             cout << "Result = " << (r>=0) ? r : -r;
             break;

         case 3: 
             int r = (num1 & num2) ? 
                 binary2decimal(num1) * binary2decimal(num2) : 0;
             cout << "Result = " << r;
             break; 

         default:
             cout << "Enter a valid choice next time";
             break;
     }

    .....
}
```